# Is HashCode.Combine commutative?

Tags: c#, hashcode

Specifically, is

```
HashCode.Combine<T1,T2>(T1, T2)
```

*commutative*? I.e. is it true that

```
HashCode.Combine(a, b) == HashCode.Combine(b, a)
```

for *any* `a` and `b`?

Comment: Have you tried it? What is the result you have found out?

Comment: Or even better, read the source code: https://github.com/dotnet/runtime/blob/master/src/libraries/System.Private.CoreLib/src/System/HashCode.cs

Comment: It's easier to read the source on https://source.dot.net: https://source.dot.net/#System.Private.CoreLib/HashCode.cs,e4f83f1fbff45fa5

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Why not carry out a *simple experiment*, e.g.

```
public static void Experiment() {
  for (int i = 0; i < 100; ++i)
    for (int j = 0; j < 100; ++j) {
      int a = HashCode.Combine(i, j);
      int b = HashCode.Combine(j, i);

      if (a != b) {
        Console.Write($"Combine({i}, {j}) = {a} != {b} = Combine({j}, {i})");

        return; 
      }
  }

  Console.Write("Seems to be commutative");  
}
```

Outcome:

```
Combine(0, 1) = -839320321 != 864340100 = Combine(1, 0)
```

So `Hash.Combine` (current implementation, .Net Core 3.1) is **not** commutative